# Zypper error while loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, sles

I'm doing some work on a Suse enterprise server and I lost connection durring a system update. Now I can no longer use zypper and get the following error:

```
zypper: error while loading shared libraries: libzypp.so.523: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

This just happened to me upgrading from 12.3 to 13.1 so I thought I'd describe how to fix it:

1. Download libzypp and zypper rpms from http://rpmfind.net
2. rpm -U *.rpm

then continue the update with:

```
zypper dup
```

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, I think we can say that your system has been deeply harmed... You have a chance to repair your system, however. At least I hope. Note that, as zypper is a really central library on SUSE systems, it may not work... Note also that I use an openSUSE, not a SLES, but things should be quite similar...

What you can try is to reinstall the libzypp library (or zypper, but it should be libzypp. At least, I hope). Get it manually from the repository you use ordinary... and hope you won't have a version problem later...

Once it's done, try to install it using directly `rpm`. Force the installation if needed. If rpm is not broken, it may work... If it does, make your update again, in order to be sure to use a coherent system.

Good luck, I hope it will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Got similar error after failed zypper dup.

Solved it by extract zypper rpm from DVD, copy it to the server, and update zypper.

```
rpm -Uvh zypper-1.14.36-1.2.x86_64.rpm

zypper dup
```